# Android studio no reconoce librería de GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, app, librería, build.gradle

Estoy tratando de realizar datos representados por una gráfica la cual uso las siguientes librerías pero no logran ser reconocidas por Android Studio, al momento de integrarlas me aparecen en color mas oscuro como si no se hiciera uso de ellas

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.LegendEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.DataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;
```

Realice la configuración de mi archivo  build.gradle(module) de la siguiente manera  para usar la librería externa la cual inserte en dependencias llamando directamente de GitHub

Agrego todo el archivo para visualizar mi configuración del proyecto y ver si no afecta algo sobre las versiones

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
repositories{
    maven{ url 'https://jitpack.io'}
}
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a013temphumsqliteidgs9a032021_180935"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

    dependencies {

        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    }
```

Anexo mi archivo build.gradle (project) para ver si me falta alguna configuración o debo de eliminar para que funcione de manera correcta

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Finalmente al correr mi código me marca el siguiente error como si no pudiera hacer uso de la librería

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente la biblioteca necesite JitPack  para poder construir el proyecto, agregua el repositorio maven de JitPack a la lista de repositorios de esta forma:

Dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto, dentro del bloque `repositories` que se encuentra dentro de `allprojects` agrega:

```
  maven { 
               url 'https://jitpack.io' 
        }
```

`allprojects` debería ser :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { 
               url 'https://jitpack.io' 
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!